# Suddenly getting axios response of nested objects in live server and array of objects in localhost

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

Yesterday my live server `axios.get => response` from calling my route `/products` was an `array of objects [{...},{...} ...]` .

```
axios
    .get("/products")
    .then((res) => {
        setProds(res.data); // output [{...},{...} ...]
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Suddenly, this morning the response from the same route `/products` became an `object with objects {"0": {...}, "1": {...} ...}` *only in live server*.

The localhost server, as usual, kept sending an `array of objects [{...},{...} ...]`.

Dev server `response.data`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Don Julio 70 700ml",
        "description": "Corporis voluptates occaecati commodi illum recusandae dicta laboriosam praesentium molestiae voluptatem perferendis est tenetur non incidunt facere.",
        "capacity": null,
        "price": 650,
        "featured": 1,
        "img": "1.jpg",
        "vap_id": null,
        "category_id": 1,
        "discount_id": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "score": 0,
        "is_available": 1,
        "best_seller": 1
    },
    {
        // product 2
    },
    ... and so on
]
```

Live server `response.data`

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Don Julio 70 700ml",
        "description": "",
        "capacity": null,
        "price": 754,
        "featured": 1,
        "img": "1.jpg",
        "vap_id": null,
        "category_id": 1,
        "discount_id": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "score": 6,
        "is_available": 1,
        "best_seller": 0
    },
    "1": {
        // product data
    },
    "2": {
        // product data
    }
    ... and so on
}
```

This is causing me some problems using `map` method. And might cause more trouble in future.

Yeah I could transform the object as I wish, but I can't understand what's causing this since my backend is the same in live and dev server:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all()
        ->where('is_available', '=', 1)
        ->toArray();

    return response()->json($products, 200); // encode array of arrays to array of objects
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to this and you will get better performance, and no junky object to array to object transformations

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::query()
        ->where('is_available', '=', 1)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($products, 200);
}
```

Your issue is data related.
You're calling Where() on the collection, wich will keep the filtered items original idexes. If one of the removed products is in the middle of the array you will end up with skipped index, wich can only be translated into an object in json format

```
[ 
    0 => 'first',
    1 => 'second',
    3 => 'fourth', // the third item has been filtered out
]
// will become this to keep the structure as the source.
{
    '0':'first',
    '1':'second',
    '3':'fourth'
}
```

In your local data, you must have the filtered items in the end of the array (the fourth in this example), so the order is not broken, and the php array can be translated to a JS array without keeping the indexes

Comment: Yeah, using `get()` instead `toArray()` helped me to have a more legible response. Thanks for that. I ommitted the `query()` call, since I found no difference using it. I dunno what hapenned that my server was sending something different.

Comment: @FerToasted i explained it in details and the `query()` is optional but calling `where()` directly gonna do some calls first that will end up calling `query()` then `where()` through the magic method `__callStatic()`.